# Can I see all the string values (resources) in one place?

Tags: android, android-studio

In my project in Android Studio, I have many different string values that I've put in different `strings-....xml` files. Sometimes finding a specific string resource gets really difficult, even when I'm using a naming convention.

So, I was wondering:

Considering that the string resources names are unique across all the files, is there any way to see all the string resources in one place? Or search through all of them?

(`Double-Shift` search doesn't actually make it easier!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new feature in the latest Android Studio 0.8.7 (only in canary channel yet) – **Translation Editor**.

[image: Translation Editor]http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio087released

Comment: That's a nice feature to have. Although I have to open this editor on **each** xml file, so it still doesn't help that much.

Comment: The Translation Editor is showing all string resources from all files for project, I have just tried it myself. Or you can use **Edit – Find – Find in Path** funcionality to search through all files in target folder.

Comment: That's good to hear. So, I think I should wait for this feature on the next beta versions.